# Panel, addons and components not showing in Storybook with react-native

Tags: react-native, storybook

i'm setting up Storybook in React Native project, 
but the right side panel that show preview components is not showing nothing, in some video tutorias that's I see, it's not happen. how i can resolve this? some more configuration is needed?

see more here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev9N4.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Storybook React native components does not appear in preview on storybook webpage. Instead when you select a component story for preview on webpage, preview of the respective component story appears on the mobile simulator. This is the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the case show in your image (component preview visible on the device, but not in the web browser) is the normal behavior based on the Issue below:

Similar question was posted in the storybook github repo [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/3353). Issue is titled *Stories not displaying in the web browser- react-native #3353*.

Answer by storybook team member @igor-dv:

> React native stories can't be shown in the browser with an
>   out-of-the-box use case - because they are react-native. As you can see
>   in the first Welcome to storybook screen or in the Readme, you should
>   perform more steps to see them on the device.

Furthermore only suggestion by same team member for enabling components on web is:

> If you do want to see them in the browser, you may set up the react-native-web. But you should understand that it won't be real native stories.

Also I don't beleive that this use case will be supported anytime soon, as another team member, @danielduan wrote:

> I personally think the web UI is of little value to most developers. We should just default to device UI only

*P.S.* All the similar issues can be found under issue #7723 [here](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7723). This being intended behavior is additionally confirmed by third team member @Gongreg:

> **This is not a bug but intended behaviour, there is no content to show in the web (it is React Native app that you are playing around, not the web).**